# iOS mobileconfig "Not Verified"

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I created a mobileconfig file with iPCU(iPhone Configuration Utility), but it is "Not Verified" when installing it to iPhone, how to verify it?

Comment: can you please help me with how to create a mobileconfig file? I created one using ipcu but when I am trying to open it from a link in iPad nothing happening. seems the file I created is not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPCU use by default a "auto-signed" and "auto-generated" key and crt to sign your mobileconfig.

If you want to sign your mobileconfig and make it "Verified", **you need to use your own certificate and key to sign it. You can use for exemple Openssl to do the signing.**

Moreover, *before iOS6*, you can juste use your own crt to sign the mobileconfig. If your certificate has been delivered by an Apple trusted CA [(listed here)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012), your mobileconfig will be "verified".

If you *use iOS6*, you have to indicate the complete certification chain during the signing process. It means you need your Certificate Authority certificate.

I am working on a product, [Appaloosa-Store](http://www.appaloosa-store.com), a way to easily distribute mobileapplication, and we will probably allow users to distribute configuration file.

Do not hesitate if you need more informations.

Comment: I create new font .mobileconfig file, I still don't know how to make it be verify? Can you help?